# Does create-react-app (CRA) removes unused parts of modules (on production build)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, create-react-app

I am wondering that does CRA removes unused parts of modules **on production build**? Let's say that I am using a little part of a module which is **1MB**, is there any way to minify the module and get the part that I want? If CRA does not do this, how can I do this?

Comment: yes  by default removes unused part. If you want to customize you can eject and configure webpack.

Comment: Webpack within CRA handles tree-shaking (getting rid of the unused parts of your code), and has done since version 2 iirc.